# Django channels API for android app

Tags: android, python, django, django-channels

I am currently developing a server for android social network app. I am using Django and I need to add a real-time chat to it. I decided to use django-channels, but I am not sure how to use auth tokens coming to the server from the android to make the authentication in chat. Also, will django-channels even work properly in this situation or should I consider something else?

Answer (score 3):

I would start be reading the following section of the Django channels documentation:

http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#authentication

As you can see you can use the session key from either the cookie, or from a GET parameter.

There are several decorators available to your web socket methods to retrieve session information.

These are:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
@channel_session_user
@http_session
@http_session_user
```

etc...

By using these you can retrieve current user and other session details.

Answer (score -1):

if you are going to use django-channels check this [blog](https://www.machinalis.com/blog/jwt-django-channels/) they wrote some decorators that do what channels sessions decorators(like those in @turbotux answer) do but for JWT.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverlow. Please expand your answer to address the question. For more info on answering, please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.